# JAVA Hibernate GetSession

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I am  having a hard time converting/minimizing this very lengthy code that I have(Session). I have been using it every time I need session. so my code is very lengthy and messy. please help! how to minimize this as small as possible? Thanks!

```
    public List<Client> listOfClientInDonation(Map map) {
    String clientName = map.get("clientName") == null ? "" : (String) map.get("clientName");    

    List list = null;
    Transaction trns = null;
    Session sess = hibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    try {
        trns = sess.beginTransaction();
        Criteria crit = sess.createCriteria(Client.class);
      crit.add(Restrictions.like("name", clientName, MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
      crit.addOrder(Order.asc("name"));
      list = crit.list();
      sess.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        if (trns != null) {
            trns.rollback();
        }
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        sess.flush();
        sess.close();
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Use Spring Boot and JPA.  They eliminate the boilerplate for you.

Comment: oh thanks for the suggestion, im using java swing just so u know sir.